# what is the iOS sleep function

Tags: ios, multithreading, sleep

I am looking for a function that puts a thread to sleep on iOS for c++ code, or even objective-c code,
sleep(0) is not recognized by my compiler

Thanks,

Comment: "`sleep(0);` is not recognized by the compiler" - perhaps `#include <unistd.h>`...

Comment: How long does the thread need to sleep for?

Comment: Just curious, what is it that you want sleep for? There are range of things you can do with time delay, from NSTimer to performSelector.

Comment: use +[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]

Comment: my oh my stupid mistake on my part, thanks :)
i forgot #include <unistd.h>

Comment: `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0]`, would do it, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Why you want to use the sleep? Using sleep seems like wrong design to me. Can you explain a bit.

Answer (score 56):

Block for .5 seconds:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.5];
```